# take in string without losing newline character until -1 pressed

Tags: java

This is my first time here and I'm learning Java basics. I need help.

I'm trying to take in a string from keyboard without losing the newline character when enter is pressed. But this is not working and i have a vague idea why (newLine() absorbs the \n [correct me if I'm wrong]) but i don't know how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "0";
while(!input.contains("-1")){
input = in.nextLine();
}
System.out.print(input);`
```

If the input is:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
-1
```

The output should be:

```
1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9
```

What I get is:

```
-1
```

I have searched but have not found an answer that helps me.
Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put `System.out.print(input);` in side the while loop

Comment: That just shows me the numbers i have entered until i press enter again, then it shows me the next set of numbers. I want 'input' to contain the output stated above

Answer (score 3):

How about doing this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "0";
String tempInput = "";
while(!input.equals("-1")){
    input = in.nextLine();
    tempInput += ("\n" + input);
}
System.out.print(tempInput);
```

You could also use `Scanner` class `useDelimiter()` as:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("-1");
```

in which case, you could get rid of the while loop all together. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are always writing a new value in `input` when you do

```
input = in.nextLine();
```

so you are not storing the previous values. Try with a `StringBuilder`:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = in.nextLine();
StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();
while(!input.contains("-1")) {
    values.append("\n").append(input);
    input = in.nextLine();
}
System.out.print(values.toString());`
```